# Como retornar uma lista de Contatos do Google?

Tags: php, json, google

Estou desenvolvendo uma view para mostrar os últimos e-mails, itens recentes do drive e etc usando as APIs do Google : http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Porém aqui não tem nada que retorne os contatos.

Alguém faz ideia de como poderia pelo menos mostrar um frame dos contatos ou algo parecido?

Comment: Amigo eu já fiz isso usando esse http://css.dzone.com/articles/google-api-%E2%80%93-get-contact-list tutorial! Qualquer dúvida me avisa. Valeu